# For which $a>0$ does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^a+a^{-k}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> For which $a$ does $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^a+a^{-k}}$$ converge?

So far, I have figured out (and I hope I'm not wrong about this) that the series converges for $a > 1$ since $\frac{1}{k^a}$ converges for $a > 1$ and $$\frac{1}{k^a+a^{-k}} < \frac{1}{k^a}$$ for $a > 1$.

The book says it also converges for $a < 1$ and specifies that it diverges for $a=1$ but I don't know how to reach that conclusion, and could use some help.

Update: Forgot to mention, $a > 0$, sorry!

Comment: It does diverge for $a=1$.

Answer (score 2):

*I am assuming $a > 0$, which is implicit in your question.*

- For $a=1$, you have $$
  \frac{1}{k^a+a^{-k}} = \frac{1}{k+1}$$
  so by [comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with the Harmonic series the series
  $$
  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^a+a^{-k}} 
  $$
  diverges.
- For $0 < a < 1$, as you noted
  $$
  \frac{1}{k^a+a^{-k}} = \frac{a^k}{a^kk^a + 1} = a^k b_k$$
  where $b_k = \frac{a^k}{a^kk^a + 1} \xrightarrow[k\to \infty]{}1$
  so by [comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) (all is non-negative) with the series of general term $a^k$ the series converges.
- For $a > 1$, as you noted
  $$
  \frac{1}{k^a+a^{-k}} = \frac{1}{k^a}\frac{1}{1+ \frac{1}{k^a a^k}}$$
  so since $\frac{1}{1+ \frac{1}{k^a a^k}}\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{} 1$ by [comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with the series of general term $\frac{1}{k^a}$ (which is a $p$-series, and $a > 1$) the series converges.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

As this is a series with positive terms, the simplest is to use *equivalents*:

- if $\,a>1$, $\,k^a+a^{-k}\sim_\infty k^a$, hence $\;\dfrac1{k^a+a^{-k}}\sim_\infty \dfrac1{k^a}$, which converges.
- if $\,0<a<1$, $\,k^a+a^{-k}\sim_\infty a^{-k}$, hence $\;\dfrac1{k^a+a^{-k}}\sim_\infty  a^k$, which converges.
- if $a=1$, we have the (shifted) harmonic series, which diverges.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{k^a+a^{-k}} < \frac{1}{a^{-k}}=a^k.$$
If $0<a<1$, $\sum a^k$ is a convergent geometric series.If $a=1$ the series is
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k+1},$$
which is divergent.